# Who is that in Dark Twist Square and how are they related to Gen Urobuchi's work?

Tags: culture, meme

A common Meme around Gen Urobuchi's works is Butcher Bingo

[image: BUTCHER BINGI!]

for the most part the images for each square is from something Gen Urobuchi has worked on being *Fate/Zero*, *Puella Magi Madoka Magica*, *Saya no Uta* and *Psycho Pass*

Since Gen Urobuchi is generally the common denominator in the images i am wondering who that is in Dark Twist and what, if any, connection they have to Gen Urobuchi or any of his works because he doesn't look like [Gen Urobuchi](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Gen_Urobuchi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [M. Night Shyamalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Night_Shyamalan), a film director and screenwriter known for making films with supernatural plots and twist endings. Some examples of films he has created are *The Sixth Sense*, *Signs*, and *The Last Airbender*. There are a lot of [memes](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/people/m-night-shyamalan) about his [signature plot twists](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/what-a-twist).

(Incidentally, I became first aware of M. Night Shyamalan memes from LittleKuriboh's Spoof Movie no Jutsu~, an abridged parody of the first *Naruto* movie.)

As far as I know, the only connection between Gen Urobuchi and M. Night Shyamalan is the plot twists thing, and nothing more than that.